# How can I modify my keyboard settings so that pressing the quotes button enters double quotes (") by default?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am looking for a way to modify my settings so that when I press the quotes key in my keyboard, double quotes (") are entered by default and having to press Shift only to enter single quotes (').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a standard US american keyboard, it would suffice to change

```
key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   quotedbl    ]   };
```

into

```
key <AC11> {    [   quotedbl,   apostrophe  ]   };
```

in the keyboard layout file to achieve this effect.

Running `xev` shows that the key <kbd>'</kbd> has the keycode 48. The file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` shows that this keycode translates to the evdev scancode `<AC11>`. The function of that key is defined in the keyboard layout file, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` for a standard US keyboard layout. That file assigns keysyms to each of the keys, referred to by the evdev scancode. The first entry (`apostrophe` by default) is issued when hitting the key, the second when hitting the key while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.